# Storage Test not working

Tags: shell-script, chromium-os

My Crosh tab is saying that the `storage_test_1` command is no longer supported, and I was just asking if this is a problem others had as well.

Comment: For the downvoters: chromium OS or chrome OS are in scope here as it's a Linux-based OS (though I'll agree the question could do with a little more details and context)

Comment: No longer supported in what version? Please [edit] answer and add more details.

Comment: Are you just expecting a "yes" or "no" answer? If not, then please provide a proper question.

Answer (score -2):

If the command is no longer supported, you don’t have to worry, Google prefer to suppress it, and instead of a `Command not found` error, you have a nicer error. But this won’t tell you how to test your drive.